# How do I find all assemblies containing type/member matching a pattern?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, assemblies, clr

I have a folder (possibly, with nested sub-folders) containing thousands of files, some of them are DLLs, and some of those DLLs are .NET assemblies. I need to find all assemblies containing types/members matching a certain pattern (e.g. `"*Collection"`, or `"Create*"`). What is the best (fastest) way to do this?

It is OK to suggest open-source libraries as long as their usage does not require to open my source code.

Comment: How about trying something and then asking a specific question if you get stuck somewhere?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe this api is useful to you: http://cciast.codeplex.com/

> Microsoft Research Common Compiler Infrastructure (CCI) is a set of
>   libraries and an application programming interface (API) that supports
>   some of the functionality that is common to compilers and related
>   programming tools. CCI is used primarily by applications that create,
>   modify or analyze .NET portable executable (PE) and debug (PDB) files.

Or you can load all with Assembly.LoadFrom(path) and call to Assembly.GetExportedTypes()